# Is it possible to define a function of two inputs is also a function of one input at the same time?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose we have differentiable function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$. Is it also possible to write something like this
$$
z=f(x,y) = f\left(x^2 - y^2\right)?
$$
So $f$ is also a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

I am asking this, because I am suppose to work with implicit differentiation. But I am not sure if the expression $f(x,y) = f\left(x^2 - y^2\right)$ is allowed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing is sure : you shouldn't use $f$ twice. You should set for example $F(x,y):=f(x,y)$.

Comment: So it is not possible to have a function of two inputs also as a function of only one input at the same time. I was trying to solve an excercise given in my calculus class: "Consider the differentiable function $z= f(x,y)=f(x^2-y^2).$ Show that $x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0$." But then this will actually make sense if we have $z=f(x,y) = u(x^2-y^2)$? I guess? Is this line of thinking correct? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write $f(x,y)=u(x^2-y^2)$ (as you have done). In this case, it means that function $f$ takes the same values along hyperbolas $x^2-y^2=c$.

Comment: Thank you! :) I understand now.

Comment: See a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2676799/305862)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted here to illustrate what I said in a comment : function $f$ defined by $$f(x,y)=u(x^2−y^2)$$ takes the same values along hyperbolas with equations $x^2−y^2=c$. Taking the case of function $u:=\sin$, here is what we obtain :

[image]
.